# Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

The browser:

**Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**

This is my Controller:

```
<?php

class Chat extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Chat_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->view_data['chat_id'] = 1;
        $this->view_data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
        $this->view_data['page_content'] = 'chat';
        $this->load->view('chat');
    }

    public function ajax_addChatMessage() {

        $chat_id = $this->input->post('chat_id');
        $student_id = $this->input->post('student_id');
        $bericht = $this->input->post('chat_id', TRUE);

        $this->Chat_model->addChatMessage($chat_id, $student_id, $bericht);
    }
}
```

When I put my model in comment in the `parent::__construct(); // $this->load->model('Chat_model');` the error is gone.

This is my Chat_model:

```
<?php

class Chat_model extends CI_Controller {

    public function Chat_model() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addChatMessage($chat_id, $student_id, $bericht) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_chatberichten (chat_id, student_id, bericht) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $this->db->query($query, array($chat_id, $student_id, $bericht));

    }

}
```

Comment: Well then your problem is in the model right? Could you show us the code you got in there? Did you construct the parent model class?

Comment: I added it in my question

Comment: Could you please use `__construct()` instead of `Chat_model()`? It is recommended by Codeigniter and maybe that's giving the issue's.

Comment: $this->load->library('session'); write this code in you controller parent constructor and try

Comment: Did all the things you guys said, still having the same error

Comment: You are calling the session helper without loading that helper. Load the helper before calling the session

Comment: For me the controller class name was conflicting with class of library.

Answer (score 19):

```
class Chat_model extends CI_Controller
```

should be

```
class Chat_model extends CI_Model
```

Comment: What if i have
class Api extends REST_Controller
(REST_Controller extends CI_Controller)

Comment: @SagarKapasi099 I am not sure what it has with this question and answer. However, [basic example](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#basic-get-example) in package docs is just that way: Api extends Rest_Controller. You should probably post separate question with detailed explanation what do you mean. Check here [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 15):

If you use Codeigniter [Modular Extensions HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) this error can occur if you forget to change your class to extend MX_Controller instead of CI_Controller

So in your case you would start your class with:

```
class Chat extends MX_Controller {}
```

Instead of:

```
class Chat extends CI_Controller {}
```

Answer (score 7):

I get the same error message when I involve the PDF library with the class name **Pdf.php** and load it via `autoload` as `'pdf'`.

My mistake, the controller that will display my page I also named **Pdf.php**, and the error message appears ( that's the reason why I found this question :) ). The problem was immediately solved after I replaced the name of my controller with another name.

Answer (score 4):

Add changes into your library configurations in application/config/autoload.php file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

and in application/config/config.php set the encryption key(any key u like)

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'thu23456789#[n,';
```

> If you still get same error then copy
>   System/library/Session/Session.php to System/library/ folder, then it
>   should work

Answer (score 2):

My solution:
Preface: **If you don't use hooks, this will not be the solution for you.**

I had this same issue, after upgrading to v3.0.6, and I definitely had everything setup correctly, as this is an existing site just being upgraded to v3+. My issue boiled down to hooks that I had loading 'pre-controller'. My hooks worked with v 2.0.X of CodeIgniter, but not with v3+.

If you are loading hooks before the session class is loaded, and your hook has a dependency on the session class, that may be your culprit. Try changing any pre-controller hooks to post-controller, or commenting them out completely to see if that fixes your issue. This is all located in application/config/hooks.php.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered with same error. I attached "session" on --->
yourproject/application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array("session");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your load library  configuration in `application/config/autoload.php` file

```
  $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

In `application/config/config.php` set the encryption key(any key u like)

```
  $config['encryption_key'] = 'thu23456789#[n,';
```

Comment: this is the key I've got: 
$config['encryption_key'] = '23KJ31HD0SFKJ3';

Answer (score 0):

In my case the library name and controller class name was same i.e my controller class name was `Ajaxer` and also my library class name was `Ajaxer`. I changed my library class name to `Ajaxer_lib` and its resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your Chat_model, try to change `class Chat_model extends CI_Controller` to `class Chat_model extends CI_Model`.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solution worked, my workaround was:

In my autoload config, I had a library called 'auth'.

however, in my custom controller, somehow it was being messed up because 'auth' wasn't being auto-loaded(I've checked everything). Since I am only using it when logging in, I removed it from my autoload config and load it in my custom controller.

I never had this issue before but suddenly one day it happened.

Using [CodeIgniter v3]

Comment: Aww your answer helped me. Because of copy and paste i extended the model class to CI_Controller instead of CI_Model.

Answer (score -1):

Add this instead of your Chat controller constructor

```
 public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('Chat_model');
}
```

This loads the session library to your controller so that you can use the methods.

Answer (score -1):

Model Extends CI_Model Not CI_Controller
class Chat_model extends CI_Model {
.............
}

Answer (score -2):

Modify your library configurations in application/config/autoload.php file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','ci_session');
```

Set the encryption key for your applicatiion in application/config/config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'sdjfkdjkfj';
```

Copy system/libararies/Session/Session.php to application/libraries/
Rename application/libraries/Session.php to CI_Session.php

Now, CI_Session object will be available through below line

```
$this->ci_session
```