# In codeigniter 3.0.3 facing issue Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have recently downloaded codeigniter 3.0.3 and tried to initialize session library via autoload. It works fine in a controller which is using session but it shows error in the home controller(which is not using session) and shows Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php. On the other hand it works fine if I load it manually in each controller rather than loading it via autoload. Following is the way how I am initializing session class in autoload.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array("form_validation","database","session");
```

and in config

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'recipexyz';
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your config session info

Comment: add the error your are getting on home controller

Comment: On another note better encryption key http://randomkeygen.com/ yours is well to short.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841942/unable-to-locate-the-specified-class-session-php-in-codeigniter

Comment: You say it's working on most of your controllers, but not the home controller??

Does your home controller properly extend the CI controller? (e.g. `Class Home_controller extends CI_Controller` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well some time this issue occur
there are two reasons

- Try use Capital `S` `Session`
- check system\libraries is there session.php available if not then get it.