# Session problem when transmitting my data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, eloquent

I use CodeIgnter with the Eloquent ORM, so here is my code I have my User controller:

First it loads the index() function and displays my view which contains my input form in order to send the information in my database to the insert() function. I don't have a PHP error but I get a blank page with this sentence without an error code:

## Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exist ('No direct script access allowed');
    class Users extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
         
        function index()
        { 
            $this->load->view('commun/menu');
            $this->load->view('insert_client_view');
            $this->load->view('commun/footer');
        }  
         
        function insert()
        {
          $users = new Users;
          $users->prenom = $this->input->post('name');
          $users->nom = $this->input->post('name2');
          $users->date = $this->input->post('date');
          $users->statut = 'client';
          $users->identifiant_u = $this->input->post('id');
          $users->MDP = $this->input->post('pwd');
          $users->tel = $this->input->post('tel');
          $users->adresse_mail = $this->input->post('mail');
          $users->save();
          redirect('Accueil');
        }
```

my model:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class Utilisateur extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps=false;
 
    public function reservations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Article');
    }
}
```

thank you in advance for your help

I found out about the subject so I tried to load the session from my User Controller $this->load->library('session');
but without success I also checked my config file and my autoload several times but nothing seemed to be the solution.

[Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841942/unable-to-locate-the-specified-class-session-php-in-codeigniter)

https://forum.codeigniter.com/post-344240.html